# How can I link to the corresponding child React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I link to the corresponding child React component using `Link` from `react-router-dom`? By passing an id to the url. Now I'm getting the id, but the component isn't rendered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-rmfn5j?file=/src/components/Taskslist.js

Parent component

```
const ParentComponent = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.id; 

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {Tasks.map((task) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <h3>{task.title}</h3>
          <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child component

```
Import Link from react-router-dom

<Link to="/task/:id">
    <Task       
       goToTask={goToTask}
    />
</Link>
```

I'm trying to render the child component when clicking on its link at the Parent component list. So the url changes, but the Child component isn't rendered and the window is empty. Maybe it's not good using at the same time `Link` and `useParams`. I'm trying to get the child component id and pass so I can link to the specific child component.

Comment: The code is rendering links to the literal path `"/task/:id"` instead of "injecting" the task id value in to the target path. Are you trying to link to a specific task, or to some sub-list of tasks by completed status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is rendering links to the literal path `"/task/:id"` instead of "injecting" the task id value in to the target path.

TaskList

Instead of wrapping an array of filtered tasks by status, filter ***then*** map each array of tasks to a link to the specific task.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Taskslist = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const newtask = () => {
    history.push("/newtask");
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Tasks</h1>
      <button onClick={newtask}>New Task</button>
      <div className="tasks__wrapper">
        <div className="tasks__tasks-item">
          <h2>In queue</h2>
          {Tasks
            .filter((task) => task.status === 0)
            .map(task => <Task tasks={task} />)
          }
        </div>
        <div className="tasks__tasks-item">
          <h2>In progress</h2>
          {Tasks
            .filter((task) => task.status === 1)
            .map(task => <Task tasks={task} />)
          }
        </div>
        <div className="tasks__tasks-item">
          <h2>Completed</h2>
          {Tasks
            .filter((task) => task.status === 2)
            .map(task => <Task tasks={task} />)
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      <button>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Task

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, generatePath } from "react-router-dom";

const Task = ({ task }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Link to={generatePath("/task/:id", { id: task.id })}>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

TaskComponent

```
const TaskComponent = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const task = Tasks.find(task => String(task.id) === id);

  if (!task) {
    // no task, render fallback UI
    return <div>No Task</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

App - the route being linked to is missing the leading `"/"` character.

```
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact={true}>
            <Login authors={Authors} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/taskslist">
            <Taskslist Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/newtask">
            <NewTask
              authors={Authors}
              onFinish={(newTask) => {
                setTasks((pre) => [
                  ...pre,
                  { ...newTask, id: Math.random().toString() }
                ]);
              }}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/errorlogin">
            <ErrorLogin />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/task/:id">
            <TaskComponent Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo in your router code. the code you have for the task id is

```
 <Route path="task/:id">
   <TaskComponent Tasks={tasks} />
 </Route>
```

should be modified to this

```
 <Route path="/task/:id">
   <TaskComponent Tasks={tasks} />
 </Route>
```

you forgot the slash /
after that it should work fine.
[what you will have after modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHKYT.png)